# How to increase java heap size memory allocation on docker-maven project?

Tags: java, docker, maven

How do I solve OutOfMemoryError: java heap space?

The project runs without error during prototyping stage in my local computer.

Dockerfikle:

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-11 as builder

COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN mvn clean compile assembly:single

FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/target/destitch-optosplit-image-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar .
CMD [ "java", "-jar", "destitch-optosplit-image-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar" ]
```

Error:

```
ADK] Initializing
[ADK] Found "WFE_INPUT_JSON" to be "{"WFE_output_params_file":"wfe_module_params_1_1.json","input_image":"/input/module_0_0/a.tif"}"
[ADK] Successfully read "WFE_INPUT_JSON". Output params will be written to "wfe_module_params_1_1.json"
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at ij.ImageStack.getProcessor(ImageStack.java:284)
    at com.apeer.modules.deStitch.run(deStitch.java:107)
    at com.apeer.modules.ApeerMain.main(ApeerMain.java:14)
```

I have tried to specified maven memory setting but it does not seems to work.
pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Xmx2048m</argLine>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like your host machine does not have enough memory to allocate by default memory limit.
if your host machine has available memory then please allocate it during running the container.

run your container with --memory = "2048m" and --memory-swap="3072m"

```
docker run -d --memory = "2048m" and --memory-swap="3072m" -t jenkins-image
```

you can check --oom-kill-disable  also.

Please read this [document](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/), you will get your answer.

Comment: I am pretty certain machine has enough memory to run. How do I go about changing memory allocation in Dockerfile. Most of the documentation I found suggest ways to allocate memory via command line

Comment: changing memory allocation in docker file won't have any effect unless you allocate the memory in docker run time.Anyway do you have any other container running in the same machine?

Comment: I see. I am rather new to docker. The dockerfile is meant for cloud application called Apeer.com. I do have a docker installed on my computer, but never run the program locally.